# Can I use a 3TB hdd as a boot drive?

Tags: installation, partitioning, hard-drive, uefi

I need a new HDD and plan on getting a 3TB one to fit all my stuff, ubuntu 12.04 install included.

So far I only have a 5yr old Asus p5qse but sooner rather than later I should have a new system with a new MB so I imagine UEFI as well.

My questions are :
Will the full 3TB be usable on my old MB?
And on a new MB?
Am I right to ask these questions, is it a BIOS problem? Or are these matters only relative to windows OSs and I should be fine no matter what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theoretically, you can format your 3TB disk to work with your old motherboard with BIOS via partitioning it with a GPT partition table rather than MSDOS. However, it's not totally foolproof. Some BIOSes attempt to validate partition tables when they should not and that can cause problems because of the "protective MBR" that a GPT-partitioned disk uses.

Do note that not all Linux disk tools work with GPT-partitioned disks. You would need to use `gdisk` rather than `fdisk` for example. The graphical Gparted and command line `parted` should have no problems with this.

So, really, there's no definite answer to this. However, all UEFI motherboards should be exempt from this problem.

If you're going to be dual-booting, you need to be sure that your new Windows OS has support for GPT partition tables (see EDIT 1). Windows will only install to a GPT if a) the OS supports booting from GPT (see below table), and b) you are using a UEFI firmware, so dual-booting using a pure GPT disk not supported -- of course you could always make a hybrid MBR.

EDIT 1: GPT features of Windows versions are kind of mixed.

```
Windows 95/98/2000/NT 4: Lol! Not a chance.
Windows XP 32-bit: No support
Windows XP 64-bit: Data disks only (no boot capability)
Windows Server 2003 SP1+: Data disks, booting only on 64-bit IA-32/Itanium systems.
Windows Vista/7/Server 2008: Data disks, booting only available on UEFI-based systems
```

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463525.aspx#X-201104111922342)

Comment: For my first question, the "it's complicated" answer is good enough for me as I lack the knowledge to understand a more developed one. And actually if I have a new system, my boot will probably be an SSD anyway so I guess you advised against me getting one :D and I thank you for saving me the trouble...

Comment: Well, I woudln't say that's a definite "no". BIOSes with the problem I mentioned are few and far between. I was just pointing out that it was a possibility, albeit a rare one.

Comment: One way to test it is to use a LiveCD/USB and temporarily wreck your MBR (after backing it up of course) and see if your BIOS complains about it. If you'd like I can update my answer with instructions on how to do that.

Comment: Also! This 2.2TB limit of the BIOS only applies to hard drives with 512-byte sectors. What is the model of the HDD you're looking at?

Comment: Windows cannot boot from a GPT disk on a BIOS-based computer, so if dual-booting with Windows is required, you should either use a sub-2TiB disk for booting Windows or upgrade the motherboard now. (Using [DUET](http://www.rodsbooks.com/bios2uefi/) is another possibility, albeit one for experts.) Windows is fine with GPT on non-boot disks, though.

Comment: @Githlar I have no preference, any 3TB will do. I was looking at the caviar ones and the barracuda. It's good to know there should be no problem, I misunderstood you and thought my chances of getting things to work were scarce. And thanks for the update.

Comment: @Smith, there is not necessity for windows actually but if I get one, I'll install it on a separate smaller disk so there should be no problem I imagine.

Comment: The Barracuda data sheets say that the +2.2TB disks can be used on legacy systems by using Seagate Disk Wizard. Presumably, this just initializes the disk as a GPT disk. The data sheet also states that there are no "hardware level changes" meaning that the sector size is still the standard 512 bytes rather than making the sector size bigger allowing CHS addressing past the 2.2TB limit. WD makes no such claims, but it GPT partition should work with either assuming that your BIOS can handle it.